# Extended Server Control DropDownList - get ListItemCollection Items ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, servercontrols

In a `detailsview` I have an extension of a `dropdownlist` server control that I have called ZZZZDropDown. The problem is that `base.Items` is empty at the time the extended server control gets called. So my logic fails as it requires the Items to have the data from the DataSourceId. I can confirm that, yes, there is data being returned from the query.

Here is the code for the **DetailsView**

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="ZZZZDV" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="ZZZ" DataSourceID="ZZZDS">
    <Fields>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Assigned To" SortExpression="AssignedTo">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:ZZZZDropDown ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="ZZZZDS" DataTextField="Employee" DataValueField="ZZZZEmpID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ZZZZEmployeeID") %>'>
                </asp:ZZZDropDown>
            </EditItemTemplate>

.......
```

Here is the code for **Extended Server Control**

```
public class ZZZZDropDown : DropDownList
{
    public override string SelectedValue
    {           
        get { return base.SelectedValue; }
        set
        {
            try
            {
                base.Items.FindByValue(value).Selected = true;
            }
            catch 
            {
                using (EntitiesModel ZZZZ = new EntitiesModel())
                {
                    var Emp = (from emp in ZZZ.ZZZZZ where emp.EmployeeID == value.ToInt() select emp).FirstOrDefault();
                    base.Items.Add(Emp != null ? new ListItem(Emp.ZZZZZZ + ", " + Emp.ZZZZZZ, value) : new ListItem("Archived Employee", value));
                }
                base.Items.FindByValue(value).Selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

My question is how can I get the `ListItemCollection` of `Items` at the time of the running of the `extended Server Control`